# why variables keep being empty on factory angular?

Tags: angularjs, instance, factory

```
services.factory('profilFactory',['$q','$http',function($q,$http){
    var factory2 = 
    {
        profils : {},
        getProfils : function(){
            $dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.get('data.json')
                .success(function(data,status){
                    this.profils = data.profil;
                    $dfd.resolve(this.profils);
                })
                .error(function(data,status) {
                    $dfd.reject('erreur recuperation des profils');
                });
            return $dfd.promise;
        },
        getProfil : function(idProfil){
            var profil={};
            var profils = {};
            factory2.getProfils().then(function(data){
                profils= data;
                console.log(profils);//all right until here profils has values 
            });
            console.log(profils);// now  profils is empty :\ and the foreach will not execute 
            angular.forEach(profils, function(value, key){
                if(value.id == idProfil){
                    profil= value;
                }
            });
            return profil;
        }

    };
    return factory2;
}]);
```

This is a screenshot of the problem : method "getProfil"
[image: this is a screenshot of the problem : method "getProfil"]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post your code here in the question and add any extra information to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, "Why are the variables empty in the factory", it's because you are using a `console.log` statement in a location where the data has not yet been loaded from the server.  To learn more, Google this: "angularjs http get promises"

```
services.factory('profilFactory',['$q','$http',function($q,$http){
    var factory2 = 
    {
        profils : {},
        getProfils : function(){
            $dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.get('data.json')
                .success(function(data,status){
                    this.profils = data.profil;
                    $dfd.resolve(this.profils);
                })
                .error(function(data,status) {
                    $dfd.reject('erreur recuperation des profils');
                });
            return $dfd.promise;
        },
        getProfil : function(idProfil){
            var profil={};
            var profils = {};
            // Run a function to get data, "THEN" we run a function to process the data:
            factory2.getProfils().then(function(data){
                // Data has now been loaded so we can process it and return it.
                profils = data;
                angular.forEach(profils, function(value, key){
                    if(value.id == idProfil){
                        profil= value;
                    }
                });
                return profil;
            });

            console.log(profils); // This is EMPTY because it runs immediately after
            // the factory2.getProfils() function which may need several seconds to
            // load data. That's why "profils" is empty. The data hasn't loaded at
            // this point.
            //
            // No data will be available at this level of the code.  Don't try to access
            // "profils" here!  Only in your .then() function above.
        }

    };
    return factory2;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log statement is outside of the callback. That is the issue. You need to console.log in the callback or use a watcher to update it when it gets changed. For future reference you should always copy and paste your code here.

Comment: i want that the objet **profils** keep the value because if not then the foreach will not execute can u help me .sorry for my english